# Converting a raw data in character array in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to convert the RAW input data from a user into a character array in Python.

```
>>> print 'your have entered:'+ userinput
>>> arrname=[]
```

I want to store the `userinput` in the `arrname` as a character array, but I'm really not sure how to do that.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Python strings can be used like lists

Answer (score 3):

Use [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function:

```
>>> userinput = 'userinput'
>>> list(userinput)
['u', 's', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'p', 'u', 't']
```

As thefourtheye commented, you can use strings like list (except modifying it). For example, you can iterate each character.

```
>>> for ch in userinput:
...     print(ch)
...
u
s
e
r
i
n
p
u
t
```

Answer (score 1):

use 'raw_input()' here is the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

so for you it would be something like this:

```
userinput = raw_input("enter something:")
```

You can then convert it to list by:

```
arrname = list(userinput)
```